# How to align buttons at the bottom left of a banner in all resolutions?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to align buttons at the bottom left of a banner. I tried with a sample code but it gets misaligned every time the resolution changes.

Tried html code here,

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 header" style="background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1b/90/7c/1b907cad177181b12cea64203dcb7623.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 12%">          
                          
                        <div class="row " style="margin-top: 46%; margin-left: 254px !important;">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row " style="margin-top: -7%; margin-left: 367px !important;">                              
                             <button class="btn btn-success">Button2</button>                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcuqpsd6/)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.header {
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1b/90/7c/1b907cad177181b12cea64203dcb7623.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 8.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 header">
    <div class="column">
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary">
        Button1
      </button>        
      <button class="btn btn-success">
        Button2
      </button>                               
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your background scaling, having a look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Or you could try using flex for the layout: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to place the buttons as desired in the bottom left corner of the banner based on the existing code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div
        class="col-sm-12 header"
        style="
          background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1b/90/7c/1b907cad177181b12cea64203dcb7623.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
        "
      >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="" style="margin-top: 12%"></div>
          <div class="" style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end">
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Button1</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-success">Button2</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To position the buttons bottom right, you need to add `justify-content: flex-end;` to the wrapping div